# How to put array as environment variable in boto3 Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there is a way to put an array as an Environment Variable in a lambda Function using Python Runtime.

Comment: Can you expand and clarify? What do you mean? Any example code, what programming language, what kind of array?

Comment: What do you mean by "using Python Runtime"? How is the function being invoked? Do you want the same Environment Variable _every time_ that the function is run? What have you tried, and what problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 5):

Environment variables are strings. There are some ways of representing a list (or array) in a string, most commonly - a comma separated list `item,item2,item3` which you can process in python code as follows:

```py
import os

env_variable = os.getenv("NAME_LIST")
name_list = [item for item in env_variable.split(",") if item]
```

I've opted to use conditional list comprehension instead of just using `str.split` because sometimes (depending on how the string is formed) there will be empty strings in the result where you don't expect them to be. Feel free to omit this part.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to use `json.dumps` and `json.loads`.

In CDK code:

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as lambda_
import json

lambda_function = lambda_.Function(
    self, "ExampleLambdaFunc",
    runtime=aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    handler="index.handler",
    code=aws_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda"),
    environment={
        "PUBLIC_SUBNET_IDS": json.dumps([subnet.subnet_id for subnet in vpc.public_subnets])
    }
)
```

In lambda (boto3) code:

```py
import os
import json

PUBLIC_SUBNET_IDS: list[str] = json.loads(os.environ["PUBLIC_SUBNET_IDS"])


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Use the 'PUBLIC_SUBNET_IDS' in your Lambda function
    
    print(PUBLIC_SUBNET_IDS)
```

```
['subnet-XXXX', 'subnet-YYYY', 'subnet-ZZZZ']
```